# How can I use the output of a command in cfengine3

Tags: configuration-management, cfengine

I want to list a directory content and use the result somewhere else:

```
bundle agent test
{

   commands:
      "ls /tmp/test/";

    reports:
    ubuntu::
       "print output here for example";  
# or add it to a variable which is how I really want to use it.
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
bundle agent test
{

    vars:
        "my_result" string => execresult("/bin/ls /tmp/test/","noshell");

    reports:
        ubuntu::
            "Output is : $(my_result)";  
}
```

See https://cfengine.com/manuals/cf3-solutions#Execresult-example

Comment: Beware!  This command will be run several times per `cf-agent` run.  See the docs on [normal ordering](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/master/reference-language-concepts-normal-ordering.html#agent-pre-evaluation-step) and the note at the bottom of [the docs for `execresult()`](https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/master/reference-functions-execresult.html).  For `ls` it may not be important, but for more expensive commands it certainly will be.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 3.3.0, you can use the lsdir() function instead.

```
vars:
  "result" slist => lsdir("/tmp/test", ".*", "false");
```

read more :
https://cfengine.com/manuals/cf3-Reference#Function-lsdir

Comment: This is actually better for the `ls` use case as it makes use of CFEngine's internal function caching and doesn't call an external command multiple times per run.  Of course, `execresult()` is more general.